# Call a new struct and get all the accessors listed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, struct, ruby-on-rails-5

```
mystruct = Struct.new(:one,:two, :three,:four)
```

How do I call `mystruct` and get a list of all the accessors?

Result: `[:one,:two,:three, :four]`.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain what, *precisely* is unclear to you about the documentation. That way, the Ruby developers can improve the documentation so that future Ruby developers don't stumble over the same problems you did. Help make the world a better place!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is better known as [`members`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Struct.html#method-i-members):

```
Struct.new(:one,:two, :three,:four).members
# [:one, :two, :three, :four]
```